# Matlab lsq curvefit parameters

Tags: matlab

I am having some issues using matlab's lsqcurvefit function to find nonlinear fit coefficients. Currently, I am getting an index exceeds matrix dimensions error when running my code. My code is simple and looks as follows:

```
function aFit = fitTwoSlit(xData,yData)

load twoSlit
a0 = 4;+
aFit = lsqcurvefit(@TwoSlitInter,a0,xData,yData);
plot(xData, yData, 'bo', xData, aFit, 'k-');
end

function Inten = TwoSlitInter(a,x)


L = 1025.; % Length in mm
lambda_l = 6.7e-4; %laser lambda in mm
k_l = 9.378e+03;   % k for laser in 1/mm
phi = k_l*a(2)*sin(abs(x-a(4))/L);
psi = k_l*a(3)*sin(abs(x-a(4))/L);

Inten = a(1)*(sin(phi/2)./(phi/2)).^2.*(cos(psi/2)).^2;

end
```

I have an array 'a' that carries coefficients being used by by intensity function. I am confused as to how I am to pass those coefficients if lsqcurvefit needs a function handle to be passed rather than a function itself.

Any help would be greatly appreciated!

Comment: `lsqcurvefit` uses the values from the initial point `x0` to determine the number and size of variables that the function accepts. You do not pass the coefficients in vector `a`.

Answer (score 0):

Why do you load data inside fitTwoSlit, since they are arguments to the function? If I have understood your question, I would expect something like

```
load twoSlit; % this should load xData and yData
```

and then aFit = fitTwoSlit(xData,yData);

```
a0 = 4; +
```

Assuming the '+' is a typo you would have defined a0 = 4. The problem with that is that your TwoSlitInter function is expecting an 'a' variable which is a four dimensional vector (you refer to a(1) ... a(4).

so suppose your a is

```
a0 = randn(4,1); % unlikely to be the best guess
```

then you could call lsqcurvefit as in

```
aFit = lsqcurvefit(@TwoSlitInter,a0,xData,yData);
```

then to plot the result you would need something like

```
plot(xData, yData, 'bo', xData, TwoSlitInter(aFit, xData) , 'k-') ;
```